# non-nullable value types in editor template for insert

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I need help resolving a design decision roadblock with a coworker. I hardly esteem his opinions, but love posting questions on Stack Overflow, so here goes :)

Suppose I have the following model:

```
public class Foo
{
  public DateTime FooDate { get; set; }
}
```

In my template, I want to create a form to do updates/ inserts to this model, so I have the following code:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(...))
{
  ...
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FooDate)
  ...
}
```

When doing an update, this will set the value of the textbox to the existing model's value, which is good.  However, when I do this with an empty model for an insert, it sets the textbox to `1/1/0001`, which is not good.

It's obvious to me as to why this happens, and the solution seems to be to make `FooDate` nullable and put a `[Required]` attribute on it.  My coworker doesn't seem to approve of this, since the `FooDate` property isn't really nullable.

The other option would be to have different form templates for inserts and updates I suppose, but that seems equally as wasteful in other respects.

Has anyone else run into this dilemma?  If so, what route did you take to resolve/get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173021/remove-default-value-for-non-nullable-properties-when-using-editfor-asp-net-mvc/7290306#7290306).  See if that is helpful to you.  I think it may solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Matt, we ended up going with this solution as well